# Finding a string in a list python

Tags: python, string, text

I have a list of words:

```
words = ["gentleman","woman","boy","girl"]
```

I am trying to check if both a full or partial string match occur within this list. for example if I have the string

```
x = "gentleman"
```

then I would find it easily with

```
if x in words
```

but how can I check for partial matches as well? For example if I have

```
x = "man"
```

and I want to match "man" as part of "gentleman". Is there a way to check for both full and partial matches?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That can easily be done with:

```
if any(x in s for s in words):
```

---

Demo (this works for both situations):

```
>>> words = ["gentleman", "woman", "boy", "girl"]
>>> x = "gentleman"
>>> any(x in s for s in words)
True
>>> x = "man"
>>> any(x in s for s in words)
True
```

What I am doing here is iterating over `words` and checking if the search string is within any of them.

---

**EDIT:** To make it reject single letter substrings, just do a pre-check:

```
if len(x) > 1:
    search = any(x in s for s in words)
else:
    search = False
```

Comment: I knew it was something easy. Thanks Alex.

Comment: This seems to be finding single letter matches, is it possible that it will only find man and not m?

Comment: @EnglishGrad It does that because it finds substrings, regardless of length. To avoid that, you could make the check happening dependent on the length of `x`.

Comment: it will also match "woman", which is not acceptable as a "man"

Comment: @salmanwahed It must be done in this way- the idea that `'man'` should work for `'gentleman'` but not `'woman'` is conceptually subjective and thus not suitable for programming.

Comment: where exactly would you put the check? in the line you gave?

Comment: I am not looking for the concept I am looking for a string match, so matching man and woman is fine

Comment: @EnglishGrad Consider accepting with the tick in that case. :)